# JQuery datatable only loads data on Chrome on local computer

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, datatable

I am using JQuery datatable to populate a Java web application. All html are rendered through JSP pages, and the data itself comes from Servlets triggered by javascript on page load.

When I deploy the web app on Tomcat, and run it on Chrome on my computer, the data loads fine. However, when I run the web app on Firefox on my computer, the data doesn't load. Similar scenarios have been seen from Internet Explorer and Opera.

I am also connected to a LAN, and accessing the web app on Chrome from a second computer doesn't load my data. It seems my data is only loaded when I run the web app on Chrome in my computer.

Here's a code snippet of the datatable initialization:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            oTable = $("#datatables").dataTable({
                        "aoColumns" : [
                            {
                                "sName" : "fullName"
                            },

                        "sAjaxSource" : 'checklistdataallteam',
                        "sServerMethod": "GET",
                        "fnDrawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
                            //The call to makeEditable is set here to make sure all the data are loaded 
                            this.makeEditable({
                                oEditableSettings: { event: 'click' },
                                sUpdateURL : 'UpdateChecklistData',
                                aoColumns : [
                                     {} //patient name; default editing                                         
                            });
                       });

 </script>
```

The servlet 'checklistdataallteam' connects to a mysql database, gets the data, converts to JSON format and populates the datatable.

What is the solution to this?

Comment: You should check your JavaScript syntax, for example when you start arrays using square brackets `[` it needs to be closed at some point. My best bet is that chrome is more permissive than other browsers, try to check firefox's javascript console to see if you get any error!

Comment: Turns out I had an extra 's' on my datatable file name. Instead of 'jquery.datatable.js', I had 'jquery.datatables.js'. I felt so stupid. It all works fine now. Thanks again!